# When using yield within a "using" statement, when does Dispose occur?

Tags: c#, file-io, using, deferred-execution

I have a question regarding deferred execution and the disposing of data.

Consider the following example:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ParseFile(string fileName)
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}

private void LineReader(string fileName)
{
    int counter = 0;

    foreach(string line in ParseFile(fileName))
    {
        if(counter == 2)
        {
            break; // will this cause a dispose on the StreamReader?
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Will the `break` statement immediately cause the reader in `ParseFile` to dispose or is it still considered in context and will lock the file open until the program itself is closed?

Comment: Write a quick console app and find out :)

Comment: Oh a side note, rather than using `break` when the counter hits two, just add a `Take(2)` to the end of `ParseFile`.

Comment: Pick up Jon Skeet's book "C# in Depth" if you want a really good explanation of what happens in iterator blocks, or just look over the language spec, as he often suggests.

Comment: @Servy Your answer below was exactly what I was looking for.  I know that there are many better methods of pulling only 2 lines from a file.  That was just a quick example to show what I was trying to get at.  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So we have several separate issues going on here.

First off, dealing with the `using` in the iterator block.  `IEnumerator` extends `IDisposable`.  The code that generates iterator blocks is actually robust enough that any try/finally blocks (a `using` results in a `try/finally` block being created) results in the contents of the `finally` block being called in the `Dispose` method of the enumerator, if it wasn't already called.  So as long as the enumerator is disposed, it won't leak the `StreamReader`.

So now we ask ourselves if the enumerator is disposed.  All `foreach` statements will call `Dispose` on the enumerator (should it implement `IDisposable`).  They do so even if you exit using a `break` or `return` statement, as well as when it finishes normally.

So you can be sure that under all circumstances the resource won't be leaked, barring the cases where *nothing* can be prevented from leaking (i.e. someone unpugging the machine).

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. In the OP's case, the iterator will absolutely dispose becuase of the break statement. But the call to ParseFile produces a reference to StreamReader inside a 'local-using' that has now gone out of scope. I think this queues it up on the finalizer queue and disposed when collected?

Comment: @n8wrl No, that's not true.  When the `IEnumerator` is disposed by the `foreach` loop it will call dispose on the `StreamReader` (assuming it was inside of the `using` at that point).  It's the way iterator blocks were implemented; to make doing this possible.

Comment: I guess we should take PsychoDad's advice and try it out becuase that would be very cool if that's how it works!

Comment: Trying to find the specific quote, but you can start reading in case you get there quicker.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/16/iterator-blocks-part-three-why-no-yield-in-finally.aspx  Pretty sure it'll be the most relevant, or the one after that, of the seven part series.